# Easy way to separate my protectedroute to different file in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I am looking for a way to separate my protectedroute from a app.js. Everything works well in my code. But if the module become to big its hard to read and manage app.js

I am looking to separate my protected routes to some component so it works here very well.

My app.js right now look like this way

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link,
    useRouteMatch,
    useParams,
    HashRouter,
    BrowserRouter,
    Redirect
  } from "react-router-dom";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
//import useToken from './Routes/UseToken';
import Login from './Login/Login';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard/Dashboard';
import Customer from './Customer/Customer';
import ProtectedRoute from './Routes/ProtectedRoute';

function App() {
    return (
        <>
        {/** use HasRouter but that will make # in the browser */}
        {/*<HashRouter>*/}
        <BrowserRouter basename='/invoice/webapps/'>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/login"><Login /></Route>
                <ProtectedRoute path="/dashboard"><Dashboard /></ProtectedRoute>
                <ProtectedRoute path="/customer"><Customer/></ProtectedRoute>
                <Route exact path="/"><Redirect exact from="/" to="dashboard" /></Route>
                <Route path="*"><Redirect from="/" to="dashboard" /></Route>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
         {/** </HashRouter>*/}
        {/** use HasRouter but that will make # in the browser */}
        </>
    );
}

export default App;

if (document.getElementById('app')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
}
```

i want to separate these

```
<ProtectedRoute path="/dashboard"><Dashboard /></ProtectedRoute>
<ProtectedRoute path="/customer"><Customer/></ProtectedRoute>
```

Comment: It seems the `ProtectedRoute` component is already separated from `App` component. Can you be more explicit about what you mean by separate them?

Comment: lol :) Read it carefully. if you read my code you can see if there is dozens of protected route then app.js become very big for front end designer so always better to separate the protected route for app.js and call protected route in some way of component inside app.js

Read the code its very clear.

Comment: Dozens is not a large nor unmanageable number, and I would fully expect any front end dev to be able to read and maintain them. Why abstract the private routes away? It just adds unnecessary code and complexity, and can also break how the `Switch` renders routes if you aren't careful with route order and path specificity. You'll want all your routes at any specific depth to be rendered together (much like Lio's answer below).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file `route.js` export and object like this

```js
const routes = [
    {component: A, path: '/a'},
    {component: B, path: '/b', isProtected: true}
]
```

and in `App.js` you can use `routes.map(route => ())` for rendering them.

```js
<BrowserRouter basename='/invoice/webapps/'>
    {routes.map((route, index) => 
       route.isProtected 
         ? <ProtectedRoute path={route.path} key={index}><route.component/></ProtectedRoute> 
         : <Route path={route.path} key={index}><route.component/> </Route>
    }
</BrowserRouter>
```

There may be some syntax errors, so I suggest you understanding my idea instead of copying.

Comment: i will try it lio today

Comment: only syntax error was  

route.isProtected 
         ? (<ProtectedRoute path={route.path}><route.component/></ProtectedRoute> )
         : (<Route path={route.path}><route.component/> </Route>)

Comment: It might miss closing curly brace. I edited

Comment: one warning i am seeing during the inspect because in array we need key.

"Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

Comment: It's not a serious problem, if you feel annoyed with it, just add `key={index}` as I edited